# RealURL 2.2.1 remove segment/pagePath completly from generated URL

Tags: typo3-7.6.x, realurl

I have a problem regarding the new RealURL version 2.2.1. After upgrading to Typo3 7.6 we got the new RealURL version. The concept in the old version (6.2) was that the pagePath in the URL was completely empty.

For example if you the following tree is:

```
page1
-- page2
---- page3
```

the url for `page3` was `http://test.de/page3.html` so the complete pagePath and subfolders were removed from the URL. In the old configuration we could get that effect if the pagePath segment in the realURL configuration was empty.

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'init' => array(
            'enableCHashCache' => true,
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
            'adminJumpToBackend' => false,
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => true,
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => true,
            'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
        ),
        'fileName' => array(
            'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 1,
            'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
        ),
        'pagePath' => array(),
    ),
);
```

In the new version it isn't working anymore. I've tried a lot now to get the same state as before. But all i get is an URL with the complete path for example `http://test.de/page1/page2/page3.html`. This would destroy all URLs on Google. Does anyone know how i can fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your database and and set the field `tx_realurl_exclude` ("Exclude from speaking URL") to 1 for all **pages** (and **pages_language_overlay**) records.
Make sure every new page has set this value by default.

Comment: Thx Bernd i will try that. But i've tested yesterday some things with the exclude but i try it again.

Comment: be sure to clear the realurl-cache, where the long urls are stored (even as fallbacks for 1 month)

Comment: I have a new project and the same problem. And that was not working so when i have to update to T3 8.7 i need another solution how to set this.